# Change header1 text color in CambridgeUS beamer style

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color

I'm using CambridgeUS beamer style for my presentation. As shown in the image, in each slide, section name is shown in the top bar, but the text color is black, which makes it difficult to see. I want to change the color to white? How can I do it?

I've seen many questions asking on changing color of title, date, institute etc. The solution is to put

```
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=cyan!80!black}
```

in the CambridgeUS.sty file and it works. But I don't know what term to use for changing that header color? I've tried using section,subsection,title,frametitle,header,header1 but with no use.

[image]

Comment: By default, CambrideUS theme has white text only in the top bar. It became black because I had configured hyperref as follows: `\hypersetup { colorlinks = true, linkcolor = black}`. Because the section name in the top bar is a hyperlink, it became black. And since every other link is supposed to be black, I didn't notice it. After removing the above config, I got white text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package `xcolor` to define your own color and then set the color of the palette using `\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}`. To change font color fiddle with `fg` and `bg` for the background. MWE follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\author{Tester}
\title{Test}

% Define your own color here
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{b3f9c6}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=black, bg=green}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Test}
\begin{frame}{Test}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks. But i don't want to change the color of the background. I want it to remain red. I want to change the color of text from black to white.

Comment: @NagabhushanSN change property `fg` in the parameter